# how to make matrix based on the row data in google spreadsheet

Tags: matrix, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-query-language

I have a google spreadsheet which matches submodules and product. Below is what sheet looks like.
[image]

What I want to do is transform this data to matrix such like below.
[image]

Can I make it with one function? I want to use it in Mmult function so it would be better matrix without labels.

I cannot catch any ID to get through it. Hope I get good clues to do it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use QUERY built-in function with [Pivot clause](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#pivot) or a Pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the result you show from the data sample provided, but I think at least close to what you want:

```
=query(A2:C5,"select B, sum(C) group by B pivot A")
```

To get a `0` in the pivot table I added a row in the source data.